# How do you deal with line breaks in libraries' mustache expressions

Tags: javascript, html

Several libraries and frameworks use `{{foo}}` for inserting data into the HTML. This typically inserts a `textNode` with the content of `foo`.

So if you have user created content like

```
message='Hello\nWorld!';
//or
message='Hello<br>World!';
```

How do show the new line in `{{message}}`? I realize that there are options in most libraries that allow you to insert HTML, but then you need to worry about sanitizing the content. Is there any way around that?

Comment: well, either allow HTML (bad) or sanitize & format the content yourself. consider using some well known format like markdown to allow the users to write rich text without allowing them HTML. there are ready-to-use parsers/compilers written in JS out there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use triple braces to output html in your variables `{{{message}}}`